# How to get ID of ImageView when using onMouseClicked method?

Tags: java, javafx

I am having trouble with getting ID of my imageViews using onMouseClicked method. In this app I have 20 ImageViews and when I click on one of them, it should change image to image from my file. So far I have this imagePicker method where I tested image change with imgViewOne, which is ID of first ImageView and this works fine.

```
public void imagePicker() {
    try {
        File file = new File("/home/zoran/eclipse-workspace/Pogodi tko sam/bin/application/iks.png");
        String localUrl = file.toURI().toURL().toString();
        Image image = new Image(localUrl);
        //imgViewOne.setImage(image);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Malformed url ex");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

I have found some answers here about getting ID of text fields or some else elements, but all of them have event handlers on which can be called `event.getID().` But here, there is no event handler so I do not know how to get ID.
I tried to set argument into imagePicker, like imagePicker(ImageView v) and then call `String id = v.getID();` but I could not change image on this attribute. 
If anyone knows the solution, please share with me. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Every ImageView has onMouseCliked method by id imagePicker.So every time clicked, it goes to this method.

```
      <ImageView fx:id="trinaesta" onMouseClicked="#imagePicker" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
```

Comment: You mention an `onMouseClicked` handler. How is it related to this `imagePicker` method?

Comment: onMouseClicked is set on every ImageView by id #imagePicker. Every time I click on some ImageView, it goes to imagePicker method.  <ImageView fx:id="trinaesta" onMouseClicked="#imagePicker"... ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a [controller method event handler](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controller_method_event_handlers) which means your method can, and typically should, have a single parameter of the appropriate `Event` subclass. In your case, the parameter should be a `MouseEvent` as you are setting the `onMouseClicked` handler. You can then get the source of the event which will be the corresponding `ImageView` (the handler was added to the `ImageView`).

```
public void imagePicker(MouseEvent event) {
    event.consume();
    try {
        File file = new File("/home/zoran/eclipse-workspace/Pogodi tko sam/bin/application/iks.png");
        String localUrl = file.toURI().toURL().toString();
        Image image = new Image(localUrl);
        ((ImageView) event.getSource()).setImage(image); // set image on clicked ImageView
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Malformed url ex");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

Note that `getSource` returns `Object` so you'll have to cast to the appropriate type.